# how to use in foreach for array_keys

Tags: php, facebook, foreach, array-key

i need to get data from array_keys
the script i use in the server side:

PHP:

```
$friends = json_decode(file_get_contents(
'https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=' .
   $facebook->getAccessToken() ), true);
$friend_ids = array_keys($friends);
```

the data of array look as above:

```
{
   "data": [
      {
         "name": "Tal Rozner",
         "id": "554089741"
      },
      {
         "name": "Daniel Kagan",
         "id": "559274789"
      },
  {
         "name": "ron cohen",
         "id": "100001553261234"
      }
   ]
}
```

i need to get all this data to an array that i can work with it.

how can i do it ?
tanks,

Comment: I don't understand. Based in the JSON data above, which values do you want?

Comment: What's preventing you from working with the array in its current form? What specifically are you trying to do with the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you mean "work with it." If the JSON response from Facebook is what you posted, you should be able to do this:

```
foreach ($friends['data'] as $friend) {
    echo "ID: {$friend['id']}" . PHP_EOL;
    echo "ID: {$friend['name']}" . PHP_EOL;
    echo PHP_EOL;
}
```

This would produce:

```
ID: 554089741
Name: Tal Rozner

ID: 559274789
Name: Daniel Kagan

ID: 100001553261234
Name: ron cohen
```

The `$friends` var would already be an array due to your use of `json_decode()`. In this case `array_keys()` isn't needed, and would only produce `array (0, 1, 2)`.

Answer (score 1):

If i understand your question correctly (and I am not sure that I do) you might want something like

```
$by_id = array();
foreach ($friends['data'] as $item) {
    $by_id[ $item['id'] ] = $item['name'];
}
```

Which will give you and array that looks like this:

```
print_r ($by_id);

Array
(
    [554089741] => Tal Rozner
    [559274789] => Daniel Kagan
    [100001553261234] => ron cohen
)
```

Which might be easier for you to work with...